# Django multivalue for a field

Tags: django, django-models

I want to have a table schema as below.

table 1: **User**

> *userid, tech, other*

here tech is a foreign key to Tech table object

Table 2: **Tech**

> *techid, techanme, scenes*

Here, I want multiple values to be assigned to the scenes.

How can I do this using django models. (Please see I used *manytomanyfields*, but there I could not get back the scenes for the techname as required)

Comment: Can you put in some more information as to what was the requirement as you said you could not get it as required.

Comment: I have posted that question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200787/how-to-access-generated-table-fields-in-django-manytomanyfield

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships If you read this documentation, it mentions how you can create an intermediate model or through model to define M2M relations. If it was upto to me I would devise a solution using that information. It will require changes to model. I am unsure if it would suit your needs.

Comment: If you are using Postgres, you could look into the ArrayField... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to implement it.

```
class Scene(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Tech(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    scenes = models.ManyToManyField(Scene, blank=True)

class User(models.Model):
    tech = models.ForeignKey(Tech, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```